# Birkat Kohanim by a Kohen Shatz

Tags: minhag, birchas-kohanim

What is the basis for a kohen who is the shatz to do Birkat Kohanim even if there is more than one kohen present like is done in at least a few Israeli Ashkenazi communities? [The Shulchan Aruch states in siman 128, sief 20](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.128.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אם ש''צ כהן, אם יש שם כהנים אחרים, (עב) כ''ג] לא ישא (עג) את כפיו
>
> If the shatz is a kohen and there are other kohanim he does not do Birkat Kohanim.

Seemingly this means that if the kohen is the shatz and there are other kohanim present he should not do Birkat Kohanim, yet in some communities the kohen shatz does go up and perform Birkat Kohanim. I checked the commentaries and could not find any answers so maybe other people have heard an answer for why some communities allow a kohen who is shatz do Birkat Kohanim when there are other kohanim present.

Comment: Please add punctuation. As asked, this question is difficult to parse due to the lack thereof.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Fixed for you. :)

Comment: Thanks, @ezra, although I think the quote was the least problematic element

Comment: Hint: you might want to read a little further on in the same Siman and maybe look at the Mishna Brurah

Comment: I think the problem is a concern that the shat'z will get confused switching roles between shat'z and *duchenin* mode. However, IIRC, I think one opinion mentioned in Mishnah Berurah states that if he is certain that he won't get confused, he may duchen with the other Cohanim. As to why a shul wants the Cohen to be shat'z, it may be as simple as that he has the best voice and the congregation feels that he is the best choice available at that time. (Agreebaly, sometimes the choice for chazzan is shul "politics", which is a poor reason, but, alas, it's done frequently, anyway.)

Comment: or it could be in israel for ashkenazim where there is birkat kohanim every day and the kohen is an avel or has yahrtzeit and in israel kohanim in avelut duchen. Or it could be sphardim throughout the world where they also for the most part do brikat kohanim daily