# Chazzan cannot start the repetition of the Amidah? Does anything change for his replacement?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

For a justifiable reason e.g. illness, the chazzan who has said the silent Amidah finds he cannot continue with the repetition. 
I see no reason for any changes in how the prayers will continue.
Are there any laws that are applicable to this situation?

Comment: Get a new chazzan?

Comment: I can only think of cases where things would be different because the individual is different https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81933/birkat-kohanim-by-a-kohen-shatz or what if, on a fast day, the original chazzan was fasting, and because he left, fewer than the minimum are fasting so Aneinu is not said (http://etzion.org.il/en/laws-fasts-prayers-fast-days)

Comment: Even if he has to stop in the middle of the repetition we get someone else to take over from there

Comment: The only difference in Halacha I am aware of in such a case, is that if one is requested to take over they should immediately accept. However that may be in a case where the Chazan is getting replaced in the middle of Shemona Esrei, perhaps if the Chazan is being replaced prior to the Chazaras Hashatz there is no difference?